# Multiple errors when moving a function to own file

Tags: c, header-files

So I have this main function, bank1.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/msg.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include"receive_message.h"

int desks = 10;
int N = 2;
int running = 0;
pthread_t tid[10];
int queue[10];
int balance = 20;
pthread_mutex_t lock;

void* getMessage(void *arg)
{
    int i;
    char* message = malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
    char** m_point = &message;
    key_t key;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    pthread_t id = pthread_self();
    pid_t pid;    
    int j = 10;

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if(pthread_equal(id, tid[i]))
        {
        key = 10 + i * 5;
            printf("\n Thread %d processing\n", i);
        m_point = receive_message(key, m_point);
            printf(" Message received: %s\n", *m_point);
    }
    }
    free(message);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    running = running - 1;
    return NULL;

}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int err;

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while(i < N)
    {
    running = running + 1;
    pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &getMessage, NULL);
        i++;

    }


    while(running != 0)
    {
    //sleep(2);
    }
    printf(" RUN OK\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And I realized I need to use function "receive_message" in other file so I tried to make a separate file receive_message.c out of it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/msg.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>

#define MSGSZ     128

struct msgbuf {
    long mtype;       
    char mtext[200];    
};

char** receive_message(key_t key, char** ret)
{

    int msqid;
    msqid = msgget((key_t) key, 0600 | IPC_CREAT);
    struct msqid_ds buf;
    struct msgbuf m_buf;

    int rc = msgctl(msqid, IPC_STAT, &buf);
    int msg = (uint)(buf.msg_qnum);


    if (msg != 0){ 

        if ((msqid = msgget(key, 0644)) == -1) { /* connect to the queue */
            perror("msgget");
            return ret;
         }

        if (msgrcv(msqid, &m_buf, sizeof m_buf.mtext, 0, 0) == -1) {
            perror("msgrcv");
        return ret;
         }
    }

    strcpy(*ret, m_buf.mtext);
    return ret;

}
```

With this header, receive_message.h:

```
#ifndef RECEIVE_MESSAGE_H_INCLUDED
#define RECEIVE_MESSAGE_H_INCLUDED

struct msgbuf {
    long mtype;       /* message type, must be > 0 */
    char mtext[200];    /* message data */
};

char** receive_message(key_t key, char** ret)

#endif
```

Now when I try to compile it as gcc bank1.c receive_message.c -o bank1 -lpthread I get these errors I can't make heads or tails out of:

```
bank1.c: In function ‘receive_message’:
bank1.c:15:1: error: parameter ‘desks’ is initialized
 int desks = 10;
 ^
bank1.c:16:1: error: parameter ‘N’ is initialized
 int N = 2;
 ^
bank1.c:17:1: error: parameter ‘running’ is initialized
 int running = 0;
 ^
bank1.c:20:1: error: parameter ‘balance’ is initialized
 int balance = 20;
 ^
bank1.c:24:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
bank1.c:55:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
In file included from bank1.c:11:0:
receive_message.h:9:8: error: old-style parameter declarations in prototyped function definition
 char** receive_message(key_t key, char** ret)
        ^
bank1.c:87:1: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
 }
 ^
```

I'd assume the error is in the header file, but I'm not sure. The file ran as intended when the code from receive_message.c was in bank1.c

Comment: Try to add a semicolon in your header file `char** receive_message(key_t key, char** ret);`. And also try adding `#include "receive_message.h"`to your c file.

Comment: Thank you, I was sure it would be something simple like that.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I cannot comment so here's an addition to what Michiel already pointed out:

Be sure to only define `struct msgbuf` only once. Right now it is defined in the header as well as in your .c file.
Also it seems like you need it in your .c file anyway, so you could declare it static in your .c file rather than public in the header file!